# How to avoid having to keep casting the argument?

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple MVC pattern. My Views implement a simple interface.

```
public interface IComponentView
{
    void Render(ComponentModel componentModel);
}
```

Here the ComponentModel is an abstract model class. Controllers are the ones responsible for preparing the new component model and call the view's Render() method while passing the new model. As you can imagine the first thing the view does inside it's own Render() function is to downcast the received parent class ComponentModel to its appropriate child class model so that all the properties and such are available for the view to use for rendering. Here is an example.

```
public SpecialMenuView : IComponentView 
{
    ...
    public void Render(ComponentModel componentModel)
    {
        SpecialMenuModel model = (SpecialMenuModel)componentModel;
        // use model to render stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than keep down casting for every single UI component I have?

Comment: What about making the model a field, pass it in through the constructor and removing the parameter from the interface Render method?

Comment: nice Question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're using this interface for, but if you want to transfer type information, why not generics?

```cs
public interface IComponentView<TModel> where TModel : ComponentModel
{
    void Render(TModel componentModel);
}
```

```cs
public SpecialMenuView : IComponentView<SpecialMenuModel>
{
    ...
    public void Render(SpecialMenuModel componentModel)
    {
        // use model to render stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

You can make that interface contravariant for bonus points.

Comment: I use the interface because the controller has a single reference to IComponentView because controller in my case is a very generic one that is being used by multiple UI components. So if I use that generics approach, my controller can no longer do .Render(componentModel) where componentModel here is abstract class ComponentModel.

Comment: @jiminssy You need to allow genericity to travel up your hierarchy. Think about it - your current code models a situation where you have ComponentViews that can render arbitrary ComponentModels and Controllers which may pass arbitrary Models to said Views. But in reality, you have a View that specialises in rendering _a kind of a Model_ and a Controller that will pass _a kind of a Model_ into a View specialised in rendering such kind. The bottom line is - make your Controller generic as well.

Comment: You are absolutely right about that. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of an easy way to do it without generics. You can however make is nicer to follow with some pattern matching, which also takes care of ensuring the cast is fine and the model is ready to work with.

```
public class SpecialMenuView : IComponentView
{
    public void Render(ComponentModel componentModel)
    {
        if (componentModel is SpecialMenuModel model)
        {
            // use model to render stuff
            model.GetType();
        }
    }
}
```